# Calculating Frequency of Oscillations About a Stable Equilibrium Point

Tags: classical-mechanics, potential-energy, harmonic-oscillator, equilibrium, approximations

Assume I have a particle $m$ moving in one dimension where function $U(x) = -Ax + Bx^2$ describes the potential energy. I am trying to figure out how I can calculate the frequency of small oscillations around stable equilibrium points.

First off, stable equilibrium occurs when $U'(x) = -A + 2Bx=0$. Hence $x_{eq} = \frac{A}{2B}$. I am trying to model the system with simple harmonic motion, thus $U(x_{eq}) = \frac{1}{2}kx_{eq}^2$. I will isolate for $k$:

$$-Ax_{eq} + Bx_{eq}^2 = \frac{1}{2}kx_{eq}^2$$
$$-A + Bx_{eq} = \frac{1}{2}kx_{eq}$$
$$k = \frac{-2A + 2Bx_{eq}}{x_{eq}} \rightarrow k = -2B$$

From this I am applying the frequency formula : $f = \frac{1}{2\pi}\sqrt{\frac{k}{m}} = \frac{1}{2 \pi} \sqrt{\frac{2B}{m}}$ . Is this a valid solution?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm a little embarrassed to say I don't know why your method works, but it does seem to give the right answer. I'm sure the problem lies when you equate the equilibrium energy to $\frac{1}{2} k x_\text{eq}^2$, but I can't articulate it well.

A slightly better method (for the given potential) would be to [complete the square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completing_the_square). If you do this, you will see that the potential energy can be written as

$$U(x) = B\left(x - \frac{A}{2B}\right)^2 - \frac{A^2}{4B},$$

and you can easily see that this is basically of the form

$$U(x) = \frac{1}{2}k (x-x_\text{eq})^2 + U_0,$$

where $U_0$ is a constant for given values of $A$ and $B$. The addition of a constant potential energy does not change the equations of motion, and so this is a harmonic oscillator oscillation about the equilibrium point with a minimum energy of $U_0$, with a "spring constant" of $k=2B$, as you have found.

So far both our methods give the same answer. However, if you consider the potential $U(x) = -A x + B x^2 + C$, where $C$ is some constant, you will see that they disagree. Of course, the constant $C$ shouldn't change the frequency, and so your method can't be correct.

---

### Doing it for a general potential

A more interesting question is how one could do this *in general*. Suppose one had an arbitrary function $U(x)$ (say the cubic function I've plotted below) how could one calculate the frequency of **small** oscillations around the minimum?

[image]

The method is actually quite nice. (I'm going to illustrate this with the function $U(x) = A x + B x^2 + C x^3$, though it works with any function.)

1. First, find the (local) minimum you want, using the standard methods. In my case, it is the point $$x_0 = -\frac{2 B}{3 C}.$$
2. Next, perform a [Taylor Expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series) about this equilibrium point up to the second order. The expansion about a point $x_0$ is thus:

$$U(x) = U(x_0) + U'(x_0) (x - x_0) + \frac{U''(x_0)}{2!} (x-x_0)^2 + \text{ higher powers of } (x-x_0)\,\,...$$

3. Since you will be expanding about a minimum, $U'(x_0)$ is zero, and $U''(x_0)>0$, so essentially all you need to do is find the double derivative of $U(x)$ at $x_0$. What this form means is that very close to $x_0$ the function $U(x)$ behaves as a constant plus a quadratic term. In other words, close to the minimum it looks like the potential energy of a harmonic oscillator! (Of course, this is only true for very small oscillations, i.e. when $x-x_0$ is very small.)
4. The last step is to realise that since you have approximated your function about $x_0$ as $$U(x) = U(x_0) + \frac{1}{2}U''(x_0) (x-x_0)^2,$$

you can compare it to an ideal harmonic oscillator and easily see (as I described earlier) that the "spring constant" is given by $$k = U''(x_0)!$$

This means that very close to the point $x_0$, this system behaves very much like a harmonic oscillator with this spring constant. In the example I've taken, this means that (curiously) $k = 2 B$ again. You can try it out with your example as well.

It might seem a little confusing to understand at first, but I hope you'll agree that it gives a very neat way to quickly find the oscillation frequency about any minimum of an arbitrary potential.

Comment: This is a fabulous solution. You are correct with your analysis with $C$, the general form helps exemplify this.

Comment: Excellent analysis!!