# Using Binomial and Taylor Expansions to Demonstrate Harmonic Motion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, electromagnetism, harmonic-oscillator

I'm doing a physics 2 self-study and I came across this question in my textbook:

A ball of mass m and charge q is constrained to move along the y axis. At the origin is a stationary charge Q. The equilibrium height of the ball is given by $y_0=\sqrt{\frac{kqQ}{mg}}$ (proving this was part 1 of the question). Prove that, if the charge is displaced from this $y_0$ by some small $\Delta y$, it will exhibit simple harmonic motion with angular frequency $\omega=\sqrt{\frac{2g}{y_0}}$.

It says that I will need binomial/taylor expansions to solve this problem, but it's not clear on the method for doing so. How can expansion approximations be used to help solve physics problems?

Comment: Related, but more general, question: [Calculating Frequency of Oscillations About a Stable Equilibrium Point](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/574614/157014).

Answer (score 2):

The [electrostatic force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coulomb%27s_law) on the ball as a function of its height $y$ is $F(y)=kqQ/y^2$.

For small $\delta$, the [Taylor series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Definition) says that $F(y_0+\delta)\approx F(y_0)+\delta F^\prime(y_0)$, where the prime indicates the derivative with respect to $y$.

The net force is then $F(y_0+\delta)-mg = \delta F^\prime(y_0)$.

Note that if the mass were instead attached to a spring and we removed the electrostatic aspect, the force applied by the spring would be $F = -K\delta$, where $K$ is the spring constant. The natural angular frequency for the harmonic motion of such a system with mass $m$ is $\omega=\sqrt{K/m}$.

Restating, for small height perturbations around the equilibrium point $y_0$, we have a restoring force $-F^\prime(y_0)$ that scales linearly with the perturbation $\delta$ with coefficient $2kqQ/y_0^3$. This coefficient is analogous to a spring constant $K$. The rest is just algebra.

Answer (score 1):

Tangentially... This might be a good time to get familiar with approximations in physics problems. It used to be, analytic expressions were the most desirable, and so people approximated special functions and unpleasant expressions with series expansions. The idea of a series expansion is converting an expression from one form (possibly a closed form) to one which is an infinite sum (a series) of more manageable terms, so that you can take only so-many terms of the expansion and get an approximation.

Series expansions can come from a lot of different places. For example, iterative methods in computation can often be put in series form; or you can take a known series like a [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series) to express something like the following:
$$ \frac{a}{1-b} \rightarrow \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} ab^k\qquad|b|<1$$
Which might be useful to clean up some expression or the argument to a function.

Series were a big point of study in the 18th-19th centuries, where you find approximations of polynomial roots (e.g. Lambert series), approximations of solutions to differential equations (e.g. Legendre functions and spherical harmonics, Bessel functions), and more.

Anyway, Taylor series, binomial series, and Fourier series are the ones most often found in practice, whether directly or indirectly; generalized Fourier series (e.g. spherical harmonics) become more common in areas that use partial differential equations and/or functional analysis.

Most of the time, the object of the series is to approximate a piecewise continuous function on a given interval, or about a given point; this is what distinguishes the Taylor and McLaurin series, for example. A key factor is also approximating the error, or at least the *order* of the error. That is, neglecting specifics, how fast does the error *grow*. To this end, we use big-O notation, where $\mathcal{O}(f(t))$ says that the term grows as fast as a function of the form $f(t)$ (multiplied by any given scalar). As an example, a Taylor expansion might be
$$ x + \frac{1}{2}x^2 + \frac{1}{6}x^3 + \mathcal{O}(x^4)  \qquad|x|<1$$
Indicating that the remaining terms will be of order less than or equal to $4$, assuming $|x|<1$. Obviously, if $|x|>1$, the order would be infinite, as $x^5$ would increase faster than $x^4$, $x^6$ faster than $x^5$, and so on.

Series expansions aren't always in absolute terms, but may be in terms of the function being approximated. For instance, shifting a function slightly from $\phi(t)$ to $\phi(t+\alpha)$, we can take the Taylor series and obtain
$$ \phi(t-\alpha) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-\alpha)^k}{k!} \frac{d^k \phi(t)}{dt^k} $$
To a first order (i.e. taking only terms of $\mathcal{O}(x)$) this is
$$\phi(x+\delta) = \phi(x)+\delta \phi'(x)$$
For $\phi'(x)$ is the first derivative. This is used in Chemomechanics answer as an example, which should help you out.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would approach the problem knowing only basic Newtonian mechanics (and differential equations). I'll try to explain exactly when and why it becomes convenient to introduce the "small oscillations" approximation.

As you say you have already proven, the ball is at rest when the gravitational force equals the Coulomb repulsion, and the equilibrium position is at $y_0 \equiv \sqrt{kqQ/mg}$. Let's say the ball is displaced some distance $y$ from this position (we could use $\Delta y$, but it looks a bit confusing in the upcoming differential equation). The net force exerted on it is then given by

$$
 \sum F_y = \frac{kqQ}{(y_0 + y)^2} - mg = mg\bigg[\frac{y_0^2}{(y_0 + y)^2} - 1\bigg] = m\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}
$$

by Newton's second law. We are thus left with the second order differential equation

$$
 \frac{y_0^2}{(y_0 + y)^2} - 1 = \frac{1}{g}\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}
$$

which is rather messy, and I'm not sure if there is an exact analytical solution. This is where the Taylor expansion comes into play. If we define a function $F(y_0 + y) \equiv y_0^2/(y_0 + y)^2 - 1$ and restrict ourselves to small oscillations ($y \ll 1$), we can use Taylor's formula to write

\begin{equation}
  F(y_0 + y) \approx F(y_0) + F'(y_0)y = -\frac{2}{y_0}y
\end{equation}

(remember, we're measuring $y$ from $y_0$). See Sam Gallagher's answer for more details on this. At any rate, our equation simplifies to

$$
 \frac{d^2y}{dt^2} + \frac{2g}{y_0}y = 0
$$

with oscillatory solutions of the form

$$
 y(t) = A\sin{\omega t} + B\cos{\omega t}
$$

where $\omega \equiv \sqrt{2g/y_0}$ is the angular frequency of the oscillation. The role of the Taylor expansion is thus to transform a very inconvenient differential equation into a much simpler form, but this comes at a cost; our solution is only valid for very small oscillations.